# vue.js / electron How to list all folder names in public folder

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm quite new in the Vue / electron...
I need to list all folder names that are in the /public directory.
Inside of these folders may be other subfolders with .pdf files.

So far i try it with:

```
require.context('@/../public/pdf/moreFolders', true, /^.*\.*$/)
```

but this seems more for displaying files inside a folder.

In the end, I want to show a menu that has the tree structure of that public folder.

Any idea of how I can display such a structure in Vue?

Comment: require is for including files into the environment during build time, or am I wrong?

Comment: i guess, dec. I have it in a function in mounted
``` mounted() {  this.importAll(require.context('@/../public/pdf/', true, /^.*\.*$/));```

Answer (score 0):

You can list files and read the content simply by using nodejs modules:

```
const fs = require('fs')
...
```

If the build should contain those files you have to add an entry in the vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      builderOptions: {
...
         extraFiles: [
          {
            from: './data',
            to: 'data',
            filter: [
              '**/*'
            ]
```

But that is only needed, if you want to use another directory, I would suggest. Public is always copied, as I know.

Comment: Thank you dec! I will try it now and will give feedback in a minute...

Comment: So far i have no errors, but i don't know how to access "data" from my component :-/
I did: from: './pdf',
            to: 'data',
but how can i use it?

Comment: The path to this data is simply ./data

Comment: it's not working. Not in development mode, neither in build.

Comment: It is difficult to solve the problem without the whole code, I think. Maybe there are some other things missing or not correct.